# Bad rendering quality using MathJax on Windows

Tags: windows, browser, fonts, rendering, mathjax

This is a duplication of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9835463/14887940), which was asked 10 years ago. Seeing no solution has been mentioned there, and no solution can be found on the internet in general, I decided to post this question again.

As described in that old question, the equations rendered by MathJax on Windows always look not so good - a little bit too thin, unclear and blurry. I am getting the same result when I use Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome / Cent Browser and Firefox. So, as explained there, the rendering problem must be due to the OS I use, namely Windows.

I have also tried applying MacType to Cent Browser, which makes the fonts on Windows rendered in different ways and look better. (Here I must use Cent Browser instead of Google Chrome, because Chrome uses DirectWrite, with which MacType doesn't work and which can not be disabled, while Cent Browser allows us to do that. See this [issue](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype/issues/360). I encountered another problem after disabling DirectWrite though - The equations rendered by MathJax look obviously bigger than normal size without DirectWrite on. But it's not the topic here.) However, MacType doesn't seem to have any influence on the rendering.

So is there any solution to this problem, as in 2022? Personally I think it's important since the poor quality of rendered equations has affected my browsing experience a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: The real question is: why? MathJax on a webpage is not a document typeset for printing, why care that it doesn't look pixel-identical? As long as the maths is _legible_ MathJax did its job. That's the point of your webpage: to show maths in a way that folks can read it. And if this is "just for you" then explain which browser you're using, because most of them can be told to use a different text rendering engine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, this is "just for me" (ofc it would be much better when it would be solved for everyone in general, but it only needs to be a question for the users here), which is similar to the case where I used MacType to make the fonts on Windows rendered more clearly. And currently I am using Cent Browser (almost identical to Chrome, though).

Comment: Then you'll want to find out what Cent is using as its text rendering engine first, and probably engage with them about the fact that they're not rendering text as crisply as you expect.